# Converting BYTE array to INT

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have this kind of code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     byte[] array = new byte[2] { 0x00, 0x1f };
     Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0));
}
```

However it does not work. It throws an exception:

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the name suggests, an [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is 32 bits, or 4 bytes, so if you want to convert a byte array to an `Int32`, it needs to have a length of at least 4, (or more precisely, it needs to have least 4 bytes after the start position).

If all you have is two bytes, maybe you meant to use [`ToInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 11):

An `Int32` is composed of 4 bytes but the array only has 2.  One way to work around this is to first convert to `Int16` and then to `Int32`

```
Console.WriteLine((Int32)(BitConverter.ToInt16(array, 0)));
```

Note that in this specific usage converting to `Int32` from `Int16` doesn't change anything because the numbers print the same.

Comment: Just as writing the decimal number "10" as "0010" doesn't change anything else either: the additional zeroes are meaningless, and you're more or less doing the same when you convert an Int16 to an Int32.

Comment: FYI, Visual Studio 2022 using .Net 6 says the `Int32` conversion is redundant.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but for .NET Core / .NET Standard > 2.1 there is new solution:

The [`System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimitives` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives) provides two static methods `ReadInt32BigEndian` and `ReadInt32LittleEndian` for this purpose.

Using this these methods has two advantages:

1. It lets you explicitly specify if your number is stored as [little endian or big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).
2. They accept a `Span<T>` which can be a performance advantage, depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `BitConverter.ToInt32` says:

> The ToInt32 method converts the bytes from index startIndex to startIndex + 3 to an Int32 value.

You need to specify at least 4 bytes, but you only have 2.