# C# Converting Each Char to Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

I am stuck with converting textbox string value to byte array.
For ex;

```
Textbox1.text="ABC";
converting to byte array as
byte[] array1;
array1[0]=65;
array1[1]=66;
array1[2]=67;
```

Then I want to write all array1 to Textbox2 as

```
Textbox2=656667
```

Shortly, Input is "ABC" Ouput is "656667".
I am working with below codes it gives error at

```
int value = Int32.Parse(arrText[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);
```

sample code

```
string text = textBox1.Text + " ";// .Text + " ";
text.Trim();
string[] arrText = text.Split(' ');
byte[] data = new byte[arrText.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrText.Length; i++)
{
    if (arrText[i] != "")
    {
        int value = Int32.Parse(arrText[i],
            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);  //gives error
        data[i] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(value);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < arrText.Length; i++)
{
    textBox2.Text += data[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array

Comment: Could you show me my error why it is happening?

Comment: What can I write in order to "int value = Int32.Parse(arrText[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);"

Comment: What error are you getting?  Have you run it in the debugger to see what the actual inputs are?  Is `arrText[i]` a valid number?

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: I am getting "C# - System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format" My inputs 'A', "AB","1234" etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639586/converting-byte-array-to-int

Comment: Same error what i got

Comment: I apoligize from u, I dont want oto convert byte array to int. I want convert char array to byte array.